# Python for loop returns NaN instead of string output

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def numberToText(number):
     if number == 1:
         return('one')
     elif number == 2:
         return('two')
     elif number == 3:
         return('three')
     elif number == 4:
         return('four')
     elif number == 5:
         return('five')
     elif number == 6:
         return('six')
     elif number == 7:
         return('seven')
     elif number == 8:
         return('eight')
     elif number == 9:
         return('nine')
     elif number == 10:
         return('ten')

def tenGreenBottles():
  print ("How many bottles to start with?")
  bottles = int(input())
  for i in range (bottles, 0, -1):
      print "%g green bottles, hanging on the wall" %numberToText(i)
      print "%g green bottles, hanging on the wall" %numberToText(i)
      print "and if one green bottle, should accidentally fall"
      bob = i - 1
      print "there'd be %g green bottles." %numberToText(bob)
      print
```

I have been playing around with this code for a while and no matter what I do the For Loop prints out NaN instead of the string. The function `numberToText` works as intended when I use the For Loop with out the string formatting.

Comment: Is this exactly the code you are running? If so, you should be getting multiple syntax errors due to the bad indentation, which is critical in Python. Please correct the indentation in your code so we can see what you are really running.

Comment: numberToText wrong indent !

Comment: When I changed to `%d` now it says "undefined".

Comment: @Adam The answer below describes it best.

Comment: You actually want `%s`, but what you *really want* is to use `.format` or better--yet, Python3.6 f-strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this instead:

```
 print "{} green bottles, hanging on the wall".format(numberToText(i))
```

**My Reasoning for Recommending `format`**

Originally, in Python the common way to perform string interpolation (which is what we're talking about here) was to use format strings (such as `%s`, `%d`, or `%g`) and a format operator between your string and the things that were to be inserted into it.

However, you have to use the correct format string for the kind of thing you want to interpolate.

For instance, to insert a string into another string, you use `%s`:

```
>>> print "%s green bottles, hanging on the wall" % "fifteen"
fifteen green bottles, hanging on the wall
```

However, if you have a number you wish to interpolate, you would typically use `%d`:

```
>>> print "%d green bottles, hanging on the wall" % 15
15 green bottles, hanging on the wall
```

If you make a mistake, you get an error:

```
>>> print "%d green bottles, hanging on the wall" % "15"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

You seemed like you are new to Python, so I recommend just using `format` instead, which is a newer and more powerful way to perform string interpolation:

```
 >>> print "{} green bottles, hanging on the {}".format(20, "balcony")
 20 green bottles, hanging on the balcony
```

When you get more comfortable with string interpolation, you can try to do more advanced stuff with `format`. You will probably never need to use `%` again to perform string interpolation. I recommend just trying to focus on and remember `format`.

Comment: I think `print "%s green bottles, hanging on the wall" % numberToText(i)` would do the trick as well (i.e,. '%s' instead of '%g')

Comment: @Sebastian it would. But, why would you use that over `format()`?

Comment: I have tried `print "{} green bottles, hanging on the wall".format(numberToText(i))` and this helped me out. Still don't understand the difference between using `%s` or `{} . format`

Comment: @Adam the simplest (minimal change to your code) fix is to change `%g` to `%s`. That's all that's really needed.  The change to `format` is an independent stylistic change to a different string formatting technique that has some advantages over `%` formatting.  But for your purposes, the results should be identical.

Comment: @TomKarzes I recommended `format` because this user seems really new to Python. Why not suggest something that will be painless in any situation as opposed to remembering when to use `%s`, `%d`, etc.?

Comment: @roganjosh I'd say for simple cases like this it's just a matter of preference. Just mentioned it because it may help the OP to understand the error: the '%g' for (certain) floats vs '%s' for strings

Comment: @erewok I agree with your reasons for recommending `format` in general, but also wanted to mention that "%s" works for all types as well. Beginners wouldn't need to remember all the other variants (%f, %g, etc.). E.g., you can do `'%s' % 1.234`, `'%s' % [1, 2, 3]`, etc. Also, it's slightly faster than `format` if performance is a concern in certain string-formatting-heavy applications. When it comes to convenience in advanced formatting cases, I like the new f-strings best, but yeah, regarding backwards compatibility, `format` is probably the overall best choice